# Julia - python pickle - cifar-10 data

Tags: python, julia, pickle

Unable to unpickle python pickle object in julia 
TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'")

```
#download("http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz","imgs_dataset.tar.gz")
#cmd = `tar xvzf imgs_dataset.tar.gz`
#run(cmd)
using PyCall
using StatsBase
@pyimport pickle
mainDir="./cifar-10-batches-py/"
function read_data(mainDir)
    dict=[]
    open(mainDir*"data_batch_1","r") do f
        dict = pickle.load(f)
    end
    return dict
end
dict = read_data(mainDir)
imgs = dict["data"];
classes = dict["labels"];
X=float.(imgs)';
Y=onehotbatch(classes,0:9);
```

I have commented the first 3 lines because I have run them before and it would take about 2 hours for my internet connection to download CIFAR-10

 
I am getting the following error:

> PyError ($(Expr(:escape, :(ccall(#=
>   /home/remon/.julia/packages/PyCall/0jMpb/src/pyfncall.jl:44 =#
>   @pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, pyargsptr,
>   kw)))))  TypeError("a bytes-like object is
>   required, not 'str'",)

Note:

- I am using Jupyter notebook
- I am using Julia 1.0.1 I have python 2.7.15rc1 and 3.6.5 installed on my system.
- I am using Ubuntu 18.04

So what is the problem?

Comment: please maybe try to slightly edit (compact) your question so it is more comprehensible for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Julia session that does all you need:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> @pyimport pickle

julia> x = [1,2,3];

julia> f = pybuiltin("open")("file.pickle","wb")
PyObject <_io.BufferedWriter name='file.pickle'>

julia> p = pickle.Pickler(f)
PyObject <_pickle.Pickler object at 0x000000003DDABC28>

julia> p[:dump](x)

julia> f[:close]()

julia> f = pybuiltin("open")("file.pickle","rb")
PyObject <_io.BufferedReader name='file.pickle'>

julia> p = pickle.Unpickler(f)
PyObject <_pickle.Unpickler object at 0x000000003DE1C5C0>

julia> y=p[:load]()
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> f[:close]()
```

Comment: That solved my problem, Thanks except 
I had to replace pickle.Unpickler(f) with pickle.Unpickler(f, encoding="bytes") because my Julia Installation is using python 3 and the pickle was encoded into python 2 see https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

Comment: My Code that causes the problem works properly in Julia Box which uses Julia 1.0, and I am using Julia 1.0.1 isn't it a Bug in Julia 1.0.1 or it is just a corruption is in my computer

Comment: you should be able to configure Julia with Python 2 using `ENV["PYTHON"]="/new/Python2/installation/directory/python"` variable. After that you need to rebuild `PyCall` (`(v1.0) pkg> build PyCall`). Once you get Python variable into Julia, I suggest serializing with some Julia mechanism (e.g. `JLD2.jl`)